# DynamoDB get items with an attribute that is a substring of a value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to query items in DynamoDB checking if one of their attributes is a substring of a provided value.

So basically, I am trying to do a query using something similar to `contains(attribute_name, :input_value)` but like this instead: `contains(:input_value, attribute_name)` (check if the attribute is inside the input value)

Ex:
If my items have the following attributes:

```
---------------------
 item_id |  domain
---------------------
1        | amazon.com
---------------------
2        | amazon.com
---------------------
3        | google.com
---------------------
```

And I use `'https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/'` as input I want the 2 first items to be returned from the query.

Is there a way to make something like this in DynamoDB?

Comment: You can simply parse the input and extract the `domain` part of the URL and then query with that exact string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do a substring match in reverse. Before making the request to DynamoDB you should remove only the domain portion from the string as thats what you want to evaluate on.